# Where did I go wrong with this definite integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to solve the definite integral $\int_0^n\pi^{ex}dx$

Wolfram says that the answer is $\frac{\pi^{en}-1}{e \ln(\pi)}$, but I got $\frac{\pi^{en}-1}{\ln(\pi)}$.  Can anyone help me figure out where I went wrong?   These are my steps:

$$
\int_0^n\pi^{ex}dx
$$

$$
= \frac{\pi^{ex}}{\ln \pi}\Bigg|_0^n
$$

$$
=\frac{\pi^{en}}{\ln \pi} - \frac{1}{\ln \pi}
$$

$$
= \frac{\pi^{en}-1}{\ln \pi}
$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your antiderivative for $\Large e^{(\ln\pi)\color{Red}{e}x}$ is incorrect. See where Wolfram's $\color{Red}{e}$ comes from?

Comment: Your answer should have a factor of $\frac{1}{e}$ since you're integrating $\pi^{ex}$ and not $\pi^{x}$.

Comment: @Anon Ah okay, I see it now.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_{0}^{n}\pi ^{ex}dx=\int_{0}^{e\cdot n}\frac{\pi^{t}}{e}dt=\frac{1}{e\cdot \ln \pi}\pi^{t}\Bigg|_0^{en}=\frac{1}{e \ln \pi}\left ( \pi^{en}-1 \right )$$
I introduced the substitution $ex=t$, and thus $e dx=dt$

Comment: Oh interesting! the question is rather old :-)